# Converting Python dataframe column to date format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe that I want to convert to a date. The values of the column are either `DDMONYYY` or `DD Month YYYY 00:00:00.000 GMT`. For example, one row in the dataframe could have the value `31DEC2002` and the next row could have `31 December 2015 00:00:00.000 GMT`. I think this is why I get an error when trying to convert the column to a date using pd.to_datetime or datetime.strptime to convert.

Anyone got any ideas? I'd be very grateful for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `utc=True` for converting all values to `UTC` and `errors='coerce'` for convert not parseable values to `NaT` (missing datetime):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['31DEC2002','31 December 2015 00:00:00.000 GMT','.']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc=True, errors='coerce')
print (df)
                       date
0 2002-12-31 00:00:00+00:00
1 2015-12-31 00:00:00+00:00
2                       NaT
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still gives me an error message: ValueError: ('String does not contain a date:', '.')